# Python3 - list & splitting

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have currently made a small program which will go to a website (API) and reads the visitted website.

This is the incomming data:

```
b'364100,749,23389954\n651718,40,37236\n-1,1,0\n264361,69,706507\n266425,68,622098\n164967,73,1091472\n-1,1,0\n191592,70,770992\n4766,99,14061919\n1901400,1,25\n27878,90,5642168\n1733031,1,20\n35862,61,303870\n348752,40,40202\n327185,40,37294\n373555,40,37437\n1762482,1,0\n265521,40,37650\n697009,1,64\n1804628,1,0\n1735100,1,0\n322506,9,1000\n1739499,1,0\n1716356,1,0\n-1,-1\n-1,-1\n-1,-1\n'
```

I've tried to put this in a list but that's not possible.
So how can I remove all the \n and b' and ' on the end, so I can put all these numbers into a list?

Comment: `23389954\n6517181` should be `23389954651718` or `23389954` and `651718`?

Comment: They should be seperated from each other, so for example \n to an ,            I hope that will work to put all these numbers into a list                                    so like                                                                                                                    list = [] list.append(x) where x is the retrieved data.

Comment: Is there any documentation for that API? Using a mixture of newline characters and comma as separators seems strange, unless they carry different meaning. (This could be multiple lines, each with comma separated values, or multiple comma separated values, each of which might have multiple lines.)

Comment: Look here: http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Hiscores_APIs

Answer (score 1):

If we have

```
data = b'364100,749,23389954\n651718,40,37236\n-1,1,0\n264361,69,706507\n266425,68,622098\n164967,73,1091472\n-1,1,0\n191592,70,770992\n4766,99,14061919\n1901400,1,25\n27878,90,5642168\n1733031,1,20\n35862,61,303870\n348752,40,40202\n327185,40,37294\n373555,40,37437\n1762482,1,0\n265521,40,37650\n697009,1,64\n1804628,1,0\n1735100,1,0\n322506,9,1000\n1739499,1,0\n1716356,1,0\n-1,-1\n-1,-1\n-1,-1\n'
```

and you want to split at whitespace (including `b'\n'`):

```
data_as_list = data.split()
```

If you want to split at commas

```
data_as_list = data.split(b',')
```

In both cases, the result will be a list of `bytes` objects. If you want strings, do something like

```
data_as_list = data.decode('ascii').split()
```

or

```
data_as_list = data.decode('ascii').split(',')
```

(Note that the separator `','` is a string now, whereas when working directly on `bytes`, we used a `bytes` separator `b','`.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're doing properly, you can use [`string.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to separate the string into a list. You can also use [`string.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove leading and trailing characters.

For example:

```
list = string.strip("'b").split("\n")
```

`list` will be

```
['364100,749,23389954', '651718,40,37236', '-1,1,0', '264361,69,706507', '266425,68,622098', '164967,73,1091472', '-1,1,0', '191592,70,770992', '4766,99,14061919', '1901400,1,25', '27878,90,5642168', '1733031,1,20', '35862,61,303870', '348752,40,40202', '327185,40,37294', '373555,40,37437', '1762482,1,0', '265521,40,37650', '697009,1,64', '1804628,1,0', '1735100,1,0', '322506,9,1000', '1739499,1,0', '1716356,1,0', '-1,-1', '-1,-1', '-1,-1', '']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The `'b` isn't part of his string, that's the Python 3 notation for a bytestring (as opposed to a Unicode string). So the `.strip("'b")` part of your answer isn't really necessary.

Comment: Ah, oops. Should have thought of that, I don't use python a lot.